# STM32 Bluepill with Arduino IDE can not blink LEDs with a few pins

Tags: serial

There are a couple pins such as PB4, PA15, and the ones near it where it won't allow me to blink LEDs with. They are stuck at a constant voltage, one that is around 1.5V, which is lower than minimum output. This happened on both STMs. The issue is more apparent when trying to blink LEDs inside of a big program. I don't know why this is.

Comment: what is your question? ... also, we have no way to guess what code you are running

Comment: Maybe it's not genuine STM or at least those which passed quality testing. I've got one of those and whole RTC isn't working properly. On the other side genuine nucleo boards are working like charm.

Comment: @jsotola As specified, I am just running the typical LED blink program within the Arduino IDE. My question is why this is occurring.

Comment: @KIIV How do you identify a non-genuine STM? I purchased these from AliExpress, but many people do and still use them normally. Everything works with the STM32, but making an LED blink on some pins, specifically with other loads on it, does not work. It contains a steady voltage and no alternation.

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf I'd guess strange behaviour would be the first sign. But, maybe you've just burned those pins by some heavy load. It's capable to drive few milliamps and some pins are weaker than others. I'd check this program on the other boards first.

Comment: @KIIV Thank you for the help KIIV. However, it's similar to another STM board I own. So I believe the board is fine. Initially I thought it was because the pins weren't PWM. But I later learned that it doesn't matter.